# Checkpassword is not function

Tags: node.js, nest

```
[Nest] 19432  - 06.05.2023 23:05:18   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] user.checkPassword is not a function
TypeError: user.checkPassword is not a function
    at UserService.findByEmailAndPassword (C:\Users\muham\AwesomeProject\back-end\src\users\user.service.ts:48:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at AuthController.login (C:\Users\muham\AwesomeProject\back-end\src\auth.controller.ts:12:22)
    at C:\Users\muham\AwesomeProject\back-end\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at C:\Users\muham\AwesomeProject\back-end\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

```
import { Schema, Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
    @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    password: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    name: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    location: string;

    @Prop([String])
    preferredSports: string[];

    @Prop([String])
    messages: string[];

    @Prop({ default: 0 })
    rating: number;

    //check if the password is valid
    async checkPassword(attempt: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return await bcrypt.compare(attempt, this.password);
    }
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
UserSchema.index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });

export type UserDocument = User & Document;
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User, UserDocument } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { UpdateUserDto, CreateUserDto } from './dto';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
        return createdUser.save();
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.userModel.find().exec();
    }

    async findOne(id: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    }

    async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
        return this.userModel.findOne({ email }).exec();
    }

    async findById(id: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
        return this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    }

    async update(id: string, updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto): Promise<UserDocument> {
        return this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateUserDto, { new: true }).exec();
    }

    async delete(id: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
        return this.userModel.findByIdAndDelete(id).exec();
    }

    async findByName(name: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
        return this.userModel.findOne({ name }).exec();
    }

    async findByEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
        const user = await this.findByEmail(email);
        console.log(user);

        if (user && (await user.checkPassword(password))) {
            return user;
        }
        return null;
    }




}
```

```
// auth.controller.ts

import { Controller, Post, Body, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    @Post('login')
    async login(@Body() loginData: { email: string; password: string }) {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(loginData.email, loginData.password);
        if (user) {
            const accessToken = await this.authService.login(user);
            return { accessToken };
        }
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or password');
    }
}
```

i need to checkpassword